# Swift Append Array to Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

Hi guys im been had an issue with this kind of array, so basically i want to pass data an array to my server which like this :

```
{adult=[["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch", "07", "September", "1989", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"],["Mr", "Tony Stark", "17", "July", "1996", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"]]}
```

and i have array like this

```
["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch", "07", "September", "1989", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"]
```

and this

```
["Mr", "Tony Stark", "17", "July", "1996", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"]
```

i create that with this code :

```
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append(title)
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append(name)
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append(date!)
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append(month!)
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append(year!)
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("0")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
    PassengerModel.passenger_array_json.append("null")
```

so i had an idea, if i append array to an array will give me that result,
and il try this :

```
PassengerModel.passenger_array_json_2.append(PassengerModel.passenger_array_json)
```

but it give me an error, anybody know, somehow i can create data like this :

```
["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch", "07", "September", "1989", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"],["Mr", "Tony Stark", "17", "July", "1996", "null", "0", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"]
```

Comment: Show the code for passenger model. Why are you trying to pass data to your server like this in an array? it would be much better to send it as a dictionary.

Comment: What about `array.append(contentsOf: anotherArray)` ?

Comment: This part: `["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch", "07",...` is a String array. I think it would be better like `{ "title": "Mr", "name": "Benedict Cumberbatch" ...}` i didn't expect to have to explain that one. Would be much better to map it to a Character model that conforms to codable wouldn't it

Comment: Also, being a web and mobile developer. I know that sending data like this, it is ordered and would have to be read in order on the server side. If a value was missed/misplaced then your data is just wrong. at least with key pairs ordering doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is your code?

```
let sherlock = ["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch"] //Implicit type of sherlock: [String] (or Array<String> if you want)
let ironman = ["Mr", "Tony Stark"]
var characters: [[String]] = [] //Here you create an array of arrays, so one entry for each superhero
characters.append(sherlock)
characters.append(ironman)
```

works. You can't append `ironman` to `sherlock`, because `sherlock` is an array containing only strings and the result would be
`["Mr", "Benedict Cumberbatch", ["Mr", "Tony Stark"]]` (which would not be what you wanted anyways and is not an array of strings anymore (the third entry is an Array...)). So you need a new array for your actors

**EDIT:**
For everyone who is looking for an answer to the title, here is an example from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers.append(contentsOf: 10...15)
print(numbers)
// Prints "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]" here
```